# Display directly first element of Sphinx index.rst's toctree instead of a blank page

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, numpydoc, autosummary

I have a Python package (https://github.com/frannerin/AlloViz)'s documentation (https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/) with the following structure:

```py
AlloViz/docs/source
│   conf.py
│   index.rst
│   README.rst
│
└───API
    │   index.rst
    │   generate.rst # only has autosummary directive that is passed to autosummary_generate
    │                # in the conf.py file to generate the .rst files in the generated/ folder 
    │
    └───generated # Files generated automatically by autosummary extension with NumPy's templates
        │   AlloViz.rst
        │   AlloViz.Protein.rst # Protein class
        │   AlloViz.Protein.calculate.rst # Protein class method
            ...
        │   AlloViz.Delta.rst # Delta class
```

I am using Read the Docs to build and host my documentation, using numpydoc, autosummary (using [NumPy's .rst templates](https://github.com/frannerin/AlloViz/tree/main/docs/source/_templates/autosummary)) and the pydata-sphinx-theme. Currently, I have three headers (three elements in the main `index.rst` file's toctree) in my documentation:

[image: Screenshot of https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/ headers]

Then, `source/API/index.rst` looks like this:

```
API reference
=============

.. toctree::
   :caption: AlloViz
   :maxdepth: 2
   :hidden:

   AlloViz.Protein <generated/AlloViz.Protein>
   AlloViz.Delta <generated/AlloViz.Delta>
```

and it renders a page (https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/index.html) that is empty:

[image: Screenshot of https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/index.html]

But I would like that, when clicking to the "API reference" header at the top of the page, it showed directly the page corresponding to the AlloViz.Protein documentation (https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/generated/AlloViz.Protein.html), which corresponds to a file generated by `autosummary` inside the `generated/` folder:

[image: Screenshot of https://alloviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/generated/AlloViz.Protein.html]

Using an `.. include` directive in the `API/index.rst` file to include the contents of the `API/generated/AlloViz.Protein.rst` file doesn't work completely because it doesn't inherit the latter file's toctree inside it (which points to the class' methods), and also throws out warnings of duplicate members, and is just inelegant. I'm open to exploring whatever options if given some pointers!

Comment: reStructuredText does not support links in headings because that is nested markup. You could switch to MyST or Markdown and its variants which do support links in headings. Or you any content under the heading to direct the user to the page.

Comment: One more option, use JavaScript or CSS to insert an image inline after it is rendered to HTML.